# devise destroys user instead updating it

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I have a very strange error i have a devise user model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :lockable, :confirmable, :timeoutable,:omniauthable and
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
end
```

and in my routes.rb I have these routes

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => {confirmations: 'confirmations', :registrations => "registrations", :sessions=>"sessions"}
```

my update user form look some thing like this

```
<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name), html: { method: :put }) do |f| %>
            <% if flash[:error] %>
                <div class="alert alert-danger fade in" role="alert">
                  <%= flash[:error] %>
                </div>
            <% end %>
            <% if devise_error_messages? %>
                <div class="alert alert-danger fade in" role="alert">
                  <%= devise_error_messages! %>
                </div>
            <% end %>

            <div class="form-group">
              <%= f.label :email %>
              <%= f.email_field :email, autofocus: true,:class=>'custom-input form-control' %>
            </div>

            <% if devise_mapping.confirmable? && resource.pending_reconfirmation? %>
                <div>Currently waiting confirmation for: <%= resource.unconfirmed_email %></div>
            <% end %>

            <div class="form-group">
              <%= f.label :password %> <i>(leave blank if you don't want to change it)</i>
              <%= f.password_field :password, autocomplete: "off", :class=>'custom-input form-control' %>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
              <%= f.label :password_confirmation %>
              <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, autocomplete: "off", :class=>'custom-input form-control' %>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
              <%= f.label :current_password %> <i>(we need your current password to confirm your changes)</i>
              <%= f.password_field :current_password, autocomplete: "off", :class=>'custom-input form-control' %>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                  <%= f.submit "Update", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-8">
                  <%= button_to "Cancel my account", registration_path(resource_name), data: { confirm: "Are you sure?" }, method: :delete, class: "btn btn-danger" %>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
<% end %>
```

When I try to update my account it destroys my account instead of updating it I am shocked why I am getting this bug please help me out Thanks in advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`button_to` generates a form, so your markup will produce a form nested within a second form.

This isn't legal html and in the past I've seen behaviour such as the submit button from one form actually submitting the other form. This would appear to be what is happening to you.

You should move your call to `button_to` outside of the form

Comment: I just converted button_to to link_to and every thing is fine now.